# Grouping population using point data in QGIS

Tags: cluster-analysis, point, qgis, population

I have a vector (point) layer that includes residential population data for each residential unit in point shape. point layers has column called " number of population" and it has different numbers as residential unit population vary from from 2 - 15 for each point.

Based on "number of population" column , I want to identify the 1000 population groups  based on the sum of the attribute value and also it should within near point group.

Currently, I am using  QGIS 3.28.3. What will be the ideal method to perform this analysis?

I Have tried via clustering analysis in GIS and it didn't get the result i was expected.